# RestSharp: RestClient constructor throws System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-functions, restsharp, jsonserializer

I am developing a .NET Core 3.1 Azure Function App in Visual Studio 2022.  After upgrading to the latest version of RestSharp today, I'm getting the following exception when I try to instantiate a new RestClient:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
> ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
> at RestSharp.Serializers.Json.SystemTextJsonSerializer..ctor()

Here is the code I'm using to instantiate the client:

```
var clientOptions = new RestClientOptions
{
    BaseUrl = new Uri("https://xxxxxxx.com"),
    Timeout = 29000
};
_restClient = new RestClient(clientOptions);
```

The error occurs regardless of whether I pass in a `ClientOptions` object to the constructor.

I have tried installing version 5.0.0.0 of System.Text.Json via Nuget, but to no avail.  I have also removed other packages which might have a dependency on a different version of System.Text.Json - but this doesn't seem to work either.

I have tried cleaning my solution, deleting the obj and bin folders, closing and reopening Visual Studio, and even rebooting my machine.  Still no go.

Any suggestions?  I'm tearing my hair out.

Comment: add nuget `RestSharp.Serializers.SystemTextJson`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply @lei-yang.  Unfortunately the suggestion to add the above nuget package didn't fix it for me.

Comment: consider commit a minimal project to github for investigating?

Comment: Interestingly, I created a new VS solution from scratch and the RestClient works now!  So I guess there's something awry about my original project.  I'll try removing nuget packages one at a time until it works (If I discover anything I will post my findings here for the benefit of others who encounter this issue).

Comment: looks good! when you face difficulties sometimes step back can be useful.

Comment: Well....it seems to be related to the Microsoft packages which are required for function apps: `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.*` and/or `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`.  I verified this by converting my test VS project into a function app.  Apparently the newest version of RestSharp isn't 100% compatible with .NET Core 3.1 Function Apps.  I am going to try reverting to an earlier version of RestSharp and/or updating my Function App to .NET 5 or 6.

Comment: what is 'function app'?

Comment: The `RestSharp.Serializers.SystemTextJson` package is deprecated, it's the default serializer for RestSharp since v107. The RestSharp package itself has a dependency on `System.Text.Json >= 5.0`, so you should normally get it installed implicitly when you add the RestSharp package. It's weird that you get this error...

Comment: This might be a similar issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/510459/error-loading-assembly-using-graph-api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting `.net core` function app you can use the **.net core** references.

Here if you are using `RestSharp` which contains **.net** remove it from your **.netcore** project

[image]

Here I am using **RestSharp.netcore** which target `.netcore` azure function

[image]

The **Resharp.Newtonsoft.Json.NetCore** package is deprecated so you can redirect to **RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson** you need to install this package.

And In your **.csproj** file you have to mention the below line of code under `< PropertyGroup>`

```
<_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput> true </_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
```

Which is used to skip the reference cache of output which previously loaded. Every time it loads new references.

[image]

Here is the issue we added the **RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson** package and **Not** added the `_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput`

[image]

After Adding the **RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson** package and `_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput`

[image]